# How to take element by student_id from one tvs table and put student_grade and student_course in another?

Tags: python, html, css, flask

Assume we have table grades with student_id - grade - cource

when i push on student_id on my page I will be forwarded to student_id page that I created.

There I want to have a table that will be dynamic. I want it to update itself when I add new cources or grades.

Table should consist of two columns: grade and cource. Im stack on /index, table shows me first elements from grades table.

this is how far I came:

/app.py

````
```def load_grades():
    grades = {}
    """Loads data from input tsv files."""
    # Load students
    print("Loading grades.tsv ...")
    with open("grades.tsv", "r") as f:
        for line in f:
            student_no, name, grade = line.strip().split("\t")
            grades[student_no] = grade
    grades = dict(sorted(grades.items()))
    print(grades)
    return grades ```
````

/index.html

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Student Number</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        {% for key, value in grades.items() %}
        <tr>
            <th> {{ key }} </th>
            <td> {{ value }} </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: What is the issue, exactly, what are you asking?

Comment: I don't understand how can I take element by student_id from one tvs table and put student_grade and student_course in another? in HTML

Comment: I don't know how to use the templating stuff, although shouldn't this be done in Python anyway? You want to combine some data to make a new table, and then display it?